# How we can automatically inject liquid code inside shop's theme using shopify app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I'm building a Shopify application and I'm interested in automatically adding a liquid content into the shop's theme.

Comment: Do you mean updating the theme or injecting liquid code dynamically while page is being rendered? And yes. Both are in a way possible. And this is not the type of question for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I use to insert liquid files in active theme.

```
    $asset = $shopify('PUT /admin/themes/' . $id . '/assets.json', array(), array
    (
        'asset' => array
        (
            "key" => "snippets/file.liquid",
            "src" => "https://yourdomain.com/file.liquid"
        )
    ));
```

To get the active theme ID i use

```
            foreach ( $themes as $theme){
                if($theme[role] == 'main'){
                    $id = $theme[id];
                }
            }
```

Let me know if this helps.